# Can't open VB6 forms in MS Word 2016

Tags: ms-word, vb6, add-in, office-addins

I have a problem with the current Word 2016 version in combination with our VB6 add-in.

The add-in loads and works fine. All functions without a dialog do what they should, except if I try to open a form. No window, nothing. At the point of `.ShowDialog()` the add-in throws an exception.

> [429]: License information for this component not found. You do not
>   have an appropriate license to use this functionality.

This don't happens with older versions of Word. Even on the same system I can open VB6 forms in our Application. The only part where it doesn't works is with Word 2016.

By searching for this error I found many potential solutions but currently nothing works. I tried to reinstall the VB6 Common Controls, to re-register, also registry hacks.

The dependencies of the add-in are simple, it only use `MSCOMCTl.ocx` and `MSCOMCT2.ocx`.

Does anyone have/had the same problem or knows, how to fix this?

Comment: I think you need to identify which part of your form is causing this license problem. You could open it in an older version and remove component by component to figure out which is causing the error. From there you would need to google that components prerequisites.

Comment: @BrunoBieri I will give it a try. But can you explain, why the form opens in our application?

Comment: I assume this is the cause: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/318597/you-receive-an-error-message-you-do-not-have-a-license-to-use-this-con

and this **could** be the solution

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/195353/file-vbusc-exe-provides-licensing-for-discontinued-controls

I haven't either tried to reproduce the behavior you experience nor have I tested the possible solutions.

Comment: @BrunoBieri Thank you for the links. The last one I already tried. Sadly with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing some controls I found out, that the problem lays in the `mscomctl.ocx` file.

After some more research I found a solution wich was posted for a problem with the `mscomctl.ocx` file in combination with office 2016 on the [office support site.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-2016-crashes-when-hovering-over-a-Common-Control-mscomctl-ocx-b8123f6b-42dc-4951-9669-5800fa7cb141) To fix the problem I copied the `mscomctl.ocx` from `sysWOW64` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\SystemX86\` (replace the existing ocx)

After this the forms shows up again. Maybe there is some bug in the current word version. Maybe this helps someone to solve the problem without many hours of research.

The reason, why the VB6 forms still works in our application is, that Word Click-to-Run version uses its own dll's in the `SystemX86` folder. So our application uses the `mscomctl.ocx` from `sysWOW64` and Word from the Office folder.

Thanks to [Bruno Bieri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1306012/bruno-bieri) for the suggestion to remove the controls one by one!